# QGIS 3.0 qgis2threejs

Tags: qgis2threejs

I have QGIS 3.0 installed, and I installed the pluging qgis2threejs, but there is no way I could find it, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: A lot of plugins have yet to be updated for QGIS 3. Because of some major changes to the program, plugins from 2.18 and earlier won't just open in 3.0. If you're just looking for 3D viewing, you can create 3D views in 3.0 under the *View* tab.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Plugins menu > Manage and Install Plugins > scroll through the ALL tab. Once you find QGISThreeJs in the menu, if its already installed make sure [image: the box is ticked].